# As a subject, is “dinner and drinks” singular or plural?

Tags: phrases, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, subjects

Is “dinner and drinks” considered singular or plural?

i.e. is it how *were* dinner and drinks? or how *was* dinner and drinks?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use:

Singular about the occasion:

> Dinner and drinks at our clubhouse last Friday was a great success,
> thanks to the organising skill of our Secretary.

Plural about the things that were served:

> The evening was a great success, and the dinner and drinks were  imaginatively chosen to complement each other.